# uninitialized constant Log4r for log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I want to see the about my debug log

so I do that as follow, but when I start the server, it saids uninitialized constant Log4r, what should I do?

```
  # environment.rb
  require 'log4r'
  Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  Rails.logger = Log4r::Logger.new("Application Log")
  config.log_level = :debug

  # your code
  logger.debug "Hmmm... That went well."
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't now about log4r, but here how i do my custom logger: first set my custom logger in application.rb

```
config.payment_logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log/payments.log'), 'daily')
```

- set name as 'payment_logger', set directory to write logs, and rotation to split whole log on small files.
then use your custom logger elsewhere:

```
Rails.configuration.payment_logger.debug("Checking payment logger! Say Hello!")
```